# Relationship with daughter's husband's cousin?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns, kinship-terms

What is the name for my relationship with my child's spouse's cousin (child-in-law's cousin) (daughter's husband's cousin) (son-in-law's cousin)?

Comment: What about your child's spouse's sister's first-born daughter's child's oldest male cousin's youngest uncle?

Comment: @Drew man, if I knew would I be here? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know your relation to *x*, consider what the relationship of your **corresponding** person, on the in-laws side has with *x*.

Here, the corresponding person would be your child's spouse's father. He is an uncle to the cousin. Hence, the given cousin is your **nephew-in-law** (or **niece-in-law**)

Comment: A *nephew/niece-in-law* could suggest a whole host of possible relationships. Far easier, if you want to be precise is to say *my son-in-law's cousin*.

Comment: @WS2 definitely clearer that way.